# Monte-Carlo Simulation of seasonal and rare order quantities

Tags: r, montecarlo

Given a seasonal demand pattern for order quantities and a historical sample of possible order quantities. How can I perform a MCS?

```
# months 1:12
mon <- 1:12

# seasonal probability density of rare orders including the material "A"
prob <- sin( -(mon + 2.5) * 2 * pi / 12)
prob <- prob - min(prob) + 0.5
prob <- prob / (sum(prob))
plot(mon, prob, type = "b", main = "seasonality and density of probabilities", xlab = "months", ylab = "probability", ylim = c(0, .2))

# historical order quantities except 0 for "A"
quantity_A <- c(15, 3.4, 3.4) # there are 3 observations, in the other months quantiy should be 0
paste("expected average of simulated 12 months=", round(sum(quantity_A) / 12, 4))
```

Want: multiple "historically" (=quantities can be: 15, 3.4 or 0) simulated years (=12 months) with an envelope of quantities like the seasonal probabilities above.

Example: `0 0 0 0 15 0 3.4 0 0 0 0`. Thus, if I run the simulation many times the shape of `quantity_A` should match the seasonal pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this is what I did. It's intended to simulate order quantities with no more than 6 non-zero order quantities per 12 months.

```
set.seed(76543)

# months 1:12
mon <- 1:12

# seasonal probability density of rare orders including the material "A"
prob <- sin( -(mon + 2.5) * 2 * pi / 12)
prob <- prob - min(prob) + 0.5
prob <- prob / (sum(prob))
plot(mon, prob, type = "b", main = "seasonality and density of probabilities", xlab = "months", ylab = "probability", ylim = c(0, .2))
```

[image]

```
# historical order quantities except 0 for "A"
quantity_A <- c(15, 3.4, 3.4) # there are 3 observations, in the other months quantiy should be 0
paste("expected average of simulated 12 months=", round(sum(quantity_A) / 12, 4))
# expected average of simulated 12 months= 1.8167

# sample 1 year = 12 months
sample_year <- function(probs, qtys) {
  res <- sample(qtys, 12, replace = TRUE) # sample historical order quantities ..
  res[(runif(12) / length(qtys)) > probs] <- 0 # .. but only accept, if greater than PDF
  res
}

sims <- t(replicate(100000, sample_year(prob, quantity_A)))

barplot(colSums(sims))
# there is definitely a peak in the high season
```

[image]

```
paste("simulated average = ", round(mean(rowMeans(sims)), 4))
# simulated average =  1.8166

colSums(sims)/sum(sims)

plot(cumsum(prob), cumsum(colSums(sims)/sum(sims)), main = "simulated vs target probabilities", type = "b")
```

[image]

But I am definitely still interested getting replies on my question.